# How find the maximum the postive integer $n$ if such $w(n)+\varphi{(n)}=1+\pi{(n)}$

Tags: number-theory

**Question:**

> if the postive integer  $n$ such $$w(n)+\varphi{(n)}-\pi{(n)}=1$$
>
> find the $\max{(n)}$,

where $\varphi{(n)}$ is  Euler's totient function  ([Euler function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function))

$\pi{(n)}$ is prime-counting function ([prime-counting function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem))

$w(n)$ is represents the number of distinct prime factors of $n$ ( [number of distinct prime factors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_factor))

It is clear $n=1$ is not such it,and $n=2$,$$w(n)=1,\varphi{(n)}=1,\pi{(n)}=1$$
so $n=2$ is such it.

$n=3$,$$w(n)=1,\varphi{(n)}=2,\pi{(n)}=2$$
is such it

$n=4$,then
$$w(n)=1,\varphi{(n)}=2,\pi{(n)}=2$$ is such it

then How find the maximum $n$?.

Thank you

Comment: I don't see why a relation satisfied by a bunch of number theoretic function is of general interest. Where did you get this problem?

Comment: Judging from his previous questions, it probably comes from a Mathematical Olympiad.

Comment: this  problem  is  from student ask it by QQ

Comment: I doubt it's from math Olympiad. In any case, it shouldn't be too hard to prove that there are only finitely many solutions using the estimates for those functions. Running a code in PARI I get $1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 18, 24, 30$ the only solutions.

Comment: The growth of $\omega(n)$ is almost negligible compared to $\varphi(n)$ which grows like $\gg 3/\pi^2 n$. Whilst $\pi(n)$ grows like $n/\log(n)$ so heuristically the set of solutions are bound to be finite. The worst case is when $n$ is a prime, but even then $\varphi(n) = n - 1$ and $\pi(n)$ grows slower.

Answer (score 6):

Well, $\phi(n)$ counts the number of integers up to and relatively prime to $n$, so the count includes $1$ and all the primes up to $n$ (that's $1+\pi(n)$), except for the ones that divide $n$ (and that's $\omega(n)$). So, $$\phi(n)\ge1+\pi(n)-\omega(n)$$ with equality if and only if all the numbers up to $n$ and relatively prime to $n$ (and greater than $1$) are prime. Now it's known that the numbers in Balarka Sen's comments are the only numbers satisfying that condition; I think there's a proof in the Number Theory text by Uspensky and Heaslet, which I don't have handy. So, we're done.

EDIT. Found it --- pages 89-90 of Uspensky and Heaslet, Elementary Number Theory. The proof there relies on Bonse's Inequality, $$p_{n+1}^2<p_1p_2\cdots p_n$$ which is proved on pages 87-89.

Comment: Darn my analytic computations.

Comment: A proof of the property of the number 30 can be found at http://planetmath.org/everypositiveintegergreaterthan30hasatleastonecompositetotative

Comment: A couple of other references: Rademacher and Toeplitz, The Enjoyment of Mathematics, Chapter 27 ("A property of the number 30"), pages 187-192 (and also the next chapter, "An improved inequality"); Benjamin and Brown, Biscuits of Number Theory, has a paper by Michael Dalezman, From 30 to 60 is not twice as hard, pages 13-15 (the paper originally appeared in Mathematics Magazine in 2000).